# Node.js - does import statement increase size of the file that's including it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This might be a duplicated question, so forgive me in advance.

I'm asking about ESModules(i.e import/export). Assume you use ESModule in node.js(without any transpiling or webpack or whatever). Only pure node.js.

When I run the following:

```js
/// helpers.js
export function func1 = ...
export function func2 = ...

/// main.js
import { func 1 } from './helpers.js'
```

Does only func1 get ended up in main.js or still, the whole thing func1, func2 is included in main.js ? Please, don't think quickly that answer is "only func1" is loaded. I understand that if you're not importing func2, you can't use it, but that doesn't mean, node source code mightn't be doing something behind the hood that still loads the module completely and not just its small parts, but still doesn't allow you to use it. This could affect the file size for example.

So in case of node.js, how does it work ? Would appreciate a very simplified explanation of what exactly `import` does ? No need to spend time how `require` works, as I understand it completely(at least the way I am content with).

Comment: The whole file will be imported,..  But if in another file you did `import { func2 } from "./helpers"`,  it won't need importing again.   If you want to keep things importing what you need, split your code into small files, you could have done -> `./helpers/func1` instead.    You can compile / bundle node js files and then you could use tree-shaking, but to be fair, just keep files small is a good move anyway..

Comment: `Assume you use ESModule in node.js(without any transpiling or webpack or whatever). Only pure node.js.` Importing something from another file doesn't impact the file size at all.

Comment: `Does only func1 get ended up in main.js`  No it remains in `'./helpers.js'` , I think the terminology `import` might be confusing you here, maybe visualise it as `import {x} from "y"` as been give me a link to `x` from module `y`..  Maybe that will help..